# Is it possible to apply a callable object to a pool of processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Whenever I call the function `Pool.apply_async`, I have to pass a function to be ran by that process. I tried to pass instead a callable object, but it did nothing. Is there any way to do it? Or would I have to design the pool myself from scratch?

The code is as follows:

```
import queue

class TaskThread(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #self.queue=queue.Queue()

    def __call__(self):
        print("in TaskThread.__call__")
        #self.queue.put(1)

pool=multiprocessing.Pool(4)
task=TaskThread()
pool.apply_async(target=task)
```

Something like that.

Comment: Can you include the code that you tried in question?

Comment: I will. Let me edit it.

Comment: Just in case it's this simple: have you tried passing the `.__call__` method as the function to apply? Like if your callable is named `C`, instead of `Pool.apply_async(C, ...)` try `Pool.apply_async(C.__call__, ...)`. It's just a thought for a workaround and it's not ideal. In these cases, the issue usually is something to do with pickling and using `copy_reg` to register your callable so it can be pickled and used with multi-processing. Class methods often cause it to choke, and maybe `__call__` is no different.

Comment: @EMC You can pass a callable object to the `Pool` methods and it should work fine. It doesn't care if its getting a function object or not, as long as its picklable. My guess is the OP is making some other mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't call `get()` on the `AsyncResult` returned by `apply_async`, nor did you use `pool.close`/`pool.join()` to wait until the child process was done working before exiting the main process. Since all worker processes inside of a `Pool` are daemons they are terminated as soon as the main process exits. That means that your example program exits  (and takes its children with it) before the child process can print anything out. You can fix it by calling `.get()` on the `AsyncResult`, or adding `close()`/`join()` calls:

```
class TaskThread(object):
    def __call__(self):
        print("in TaskThread.__call__")

pool=multiprocessing.Pool(4)
task=TaskThread()
pool.apply_async(task)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Or:

```
class TaskThread(object):
    def __call__(self):
        print("in TaskThread.__call__")

pool=multiprocessing.Pool(4)
task=TaskThread()
result = pool.apply_async(task)
result.get()
```

**Edit:**

In order to pass a `Queue` the way you're trying, you'd need to do something like this:

```
import multiprocessing


class TaskThread(object):
    def __init__(self, manager):
        self.queue = manager.Queue()

    def __call__(self):
        print("in TaskThread.__call__")
        self.queue.put(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    task=TaskThread(m)
    result = pool.apply_async(task)
    result.get()
    print(task.queue.get())
```

Output:

```
in TaskThread.__call__
1
```

Comment: Got it. If I eliminate the queue from my code it works. If I don't eliminate it, then it gives the pickle error.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas Ah, yes, that's a different issue. First, you should be using a `multiprocessing.Queue`, not a `queue.Queue`. However, even then, you can't pass a normal `multiprocessing.Queue` between processes like this (they're not allowed to be pickled). You'd have to use a `multiprocessing.Manager.Queue` instead.

Comment: @JadieldeArmas I've edited my answer to show you how you could pass a `Queue` between processes.

Comment: Yet, if instead I keep `queue.Queue` in my code, but instead of using a pool I do the following, I don't have any pickle issues. Do you know why?

Comment: `task=TaskThread(); p=multiprocessing.Process(target=task); p.start(); p.join(); `

Comment: @JadieldeArmas That won't throw an error if you're on Linux or OSX, but it doesn't actually *work*. It *appears* to work because when you pass `task` to `Process.__init__`, `task` is inherited by the child process via `os.fork`, which means `task` (and therefore the `Queue` inside of `task`) doesn't need to be pickled. However, `queue.Queue` isn't process-safe; changes you make to the `Queue` in one process won't be reflected in any other processes. If you used a `multiprocessing.Queue`, though, it would work properly on all platforms.